# add days to date using vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

in the data function I have created tomorrow variable with the date of today then I have set it by appenden 1 day to it but I'm getting this error

```js
data(){
return{
  tomorrow: new Date(),
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1),
};
},
```

> > error  Parsing error: Unexpected token .

Comment: As a WAG, try removing the semi-colon on the 4th line. It's illegal in the JSON or Tuple, or whatever that data structure that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data property is design for storing variables, not invoking functions or adding logic like you're trying to do.

Try computed property:

```
computed: {
  tomorrow() {
    const d = new Date()
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)
    return d 
  }
}
```

And then in your template you can do `{{ tomorrow }}` or in your vue component `this.tomorrow`

Comment: I have a question, under computed property is it possible to create multiple variable with the same type ? exp: let aa, bb = new Date ();

Comment: Yes, its just normal javascript with vuejs component around it.